# this.title is not a function on datatables

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I use DataTables on Angular7. I have js function on .ts file. And I get 'this.title is not a function' error.

code in my view file is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ...
        initComplete: function () {
            const that = this;
            that.api().columns().every(function (index) {
                var e;
                switch (this.title()) {
                    case "Description":
                        e = $('<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-filter m-input" data-col-index="' 
                            + this.index() + '"/>');
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can you show me your this.title. It's it method or variable?. I think thats the mistake.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar hi, It's not in my .ts file. It should be a function in datatables.js. And I import datatables.net but still I get the error.

Comment: Seems that `column().title()` is a [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/column().title()) have you registered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to modify DOM element that corresponds to column header, you may need to employ [column().header()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header()) method. So your `this.title()` should be `this.header().textContent`.

Comment: You're quite welcome, don't forget to mark your question answered. If you mean the value of cells within the column, it's `column().data()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this to get column name and it works for me.

```
    var table = $("#extable").DataTable();
    var column_name= table.column(0).header().innerText;
```